# 2nd time calling PreparedStatement is not working after closing connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle10g

I'm trying to execute 2nd time `PreparedStatement`, but it fails if I close `DriverManager.getConnection`

the code:

```
public void getRates(String id) throws Exception, DBException {

        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs    = null;

        try {

            conn = getConnection();

            if (ratesQueryStmt == null){
                ratesQueryStmt = conn.prepareStatement(ratesQuery); 
            }
            ratesQueryStmt.setString(1, id);

            ratesQueryStmt.setQueryTimeout(m_nTimeout);

            rs = ratesQueryStmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println("!!!\n\nDATE = " + rs.getString("RATE_DAY") + " PURCHASE_PRICE = " + rs.getString("PURCHASE_PRICE") + " SELLING_PRICE = " + rs.getString("SELLING_PRICE"));
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            Utility.trace(m_session, "SQL exception - code: "+String.valueOf(e.getErrorCode())+" "+e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            DBAccess.closeEverything(rs, ratesQueryStmt, conn); //DO NOT WORK BECAUSE OF CLOSING CONNECTION (conn)
        }
```

So first time it works just fine, but when I try call this method twice it shows error :(

```
        DBAccess.getInstance(mySession).getRates("USD"); //WORKS
        DBAccess.getInstance(mySession).getRates("EUR"); // NOT WORKING
```

error stack

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl._createOrGetDBItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:825)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl.setBytesBindItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:2520)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setItem(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1248)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1690)
    at asteros.DBAccess.getRates(DBAccess.java:141) //ratesQueryStmt.setString(1, id);
```

if I DO not close connection everything works..

Thank you!

**UPD:** source of getConnection()

```
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {

        Utility.trace(m_session, "DB string: "+m_strDBString+" user: "+m_strUser+" password: "+m_strPassword);
        System.out.println("DB string: "+m_strDBString+" user: "+m_strUser+" password: "+m_strPassword);

        Driver dr = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(dr);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(m_strDBString, m_strUser, m_strPassword);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }

    return conn;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect? if you close the connection, then it won't work again. Where do you re-open it the second time?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer conn = getConnection();

Comment: **which** `getConnection()` and if it's your code, then what does that method do?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer added to question, pls, see update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instances are tied to the connection used to prepare them, as far as I'm aware. You can't use the `PreparedStatement` after closing the connection, even if you open another one later.

Comment: @VextoR: You can keep the connection open as long as you like, although beware that some JDBC providers don't like the connection to be open for *long* periods of time (this is why connection pools tend to recycle connections [close old ones and open a new ones] periodically). The usual thing, instead, is to prepare the statement each time, or to use structures to associate prepared statements with the connection that created them as long as you keep the connection open. It may be worth searching around for some examples of JDBC best practices.

Comment: thanks, that is very bad :( So I need to use usual Statement and not Prepared one, so I can close connection. sad

Comment: @VextoR: why? You can use prepared statements, you just need to prepare them each time (and no: that *won't* usually be a bad thing).

Comment: @VextoR: No, you still want to use `PreparedStatement` (to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks by using the parameter substitution stuff).